# Devolver formato de fecha yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, formato

He intentado con varios formatos y no llego al que necesito `2021-12-26`.

Mi código está de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT 
    RC.Usuario[Usuario Operador],
    RC.NombreUsuario[Nombre del Usuario Operador],
    RC.clExpediente [Atendimento],
    --LEFT((RC.Fecha),10) AS [Data],
    --RIGHT((RC.Fecha),8) AS [Hora],

    (RC.Fecha, '%Y-%m-%d') FechaStr, 
    (RC.Fecha,'%H:%i:%s')  HoraStr,
    DATE(RC.Fecha)  Fecha,
    TIME(RC.Fecha)  Hora

    ES.dsEstatus [Status],
    RC.Observaciones [Motivo],
    RC.dsServicio [Serviço],
    RC.dsSubservicio [Tipo de Serviço],
    RC.NombreOpe [Prestador Nome Fantasia],
    RC.NombreRZ [Prestador Razão Social],
    RC.dsCuenta [Conta],
    RC.Ciudad [Ciudad],
    RC.Estado [Estado]
    FROM @RelatorioCancelado RC
        INNER JOIN dbo.Expediente E ON (E.clExpediente=RC.clExpediente)
        INNER JOIN dbo.cServicio S ON  (S.clServicio=E.clServicio)
        LEFT JOIN dbo.cEstatus ES ON (ES.clEstatus=RC.clEstatus)
    WHERE E.clExpediente>0;
```

y me muestra la fecha asi `diciembre 26 2021`

Comment: Con qué formatos has intentado y cómo? Aquí solamente se ve el LEFT de fecha y no se ve qué intentaste hacer (por si la falla está en otra cosa y no en tu aproximación). Por favor, ve a [edit] tu pregunta y añade los detalles correspondientes (qué probaste y por qué falló)

Comment: ya agrege los que intente e intente otros mas, quisiera saber por que no me funciona

Comment: `CONVERT(varchar(10),RC.Fecha,120)`

Comment: me dio este error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.

Comment: tendrías que poner el select completo que estás usando

Comment: RC.Fecha CONVERT(varchar(1000),RC.Fecha,120) asi?

Comment: SELECT 
      RC.Usuario[Usuario Operador],
      RC.NombreUsuario[Nombre del Usuario Operador],
      RC.clExpediente [Atendimento],
      --RC.Fecha [Data/Hora],
      --REPLACE(RC.Fecha( GETDATE(), 1), '', '') AS [MMDDYY],
      LEFT((RC.Fecha),11) AS fecha, 
      RIGHT((RC.Fecha),8) as hora,
      ES.dsEstatus [Status],

Comment: Ese código no es funcional. En Sql Server que es la etiqueta que has puesto `(RC.Fecha, '%Y-%m-%d') FechaStr`, eso no funciona. Por otro lado, si el problema es de conversión de una columna a un formato, edita la pregunta, pega una definición de una tabla con la columna que te da problemas (a mi parece un varchar). Pega un script de inserción con algunos ejemplos de los datos que tienes realmente y cual es la salida esperada, y así obtendrás una respuesta acorde a lo que necesitas.